# Webstorm: Ctrl + Arrow not working. How to fix?

Tags: linux, phpstorm, webstorm

I downloaded Webstorm 10.0.2 and noticed that when I pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> it selects char as <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> but not jumps over word.

And at Keymap Settings when I'm trying to add shortcut and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> it doesn't show this shortcut, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Any  other</kbd> works normally.

Also, at PhpStorm 7.1.3 <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd> works normally.

Any ideas how to return normal behaviour of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>/<kbd>Right</kbd>?

OS Linux Mint 17
java version "1.7.0_79"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.5) (7u79-2.5.5-0ubuntu0.14.04.2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128418#comment=27-807784) workaround - does it help?

Comment: Yeah, it works. Idea probably not work well with gxNeur